# Changing origin and destination value on click on Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to change my origin and destination (Lat and Lng) on click, this is my atual code

```
ser.route({ 'origin': new google.maps.LatLng(-23.563594, -46.654129), 'destination':  new google.maps.LatLng(
-23.563672, -46.640396), 'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},function(res,sts) {
        if(sts=='OK')ren.setDirections(res);    
    })
```

I want to change this values to draw a path, for example, I click on one point, them click in another point, so it get this values and draw a path.

I have a path but only with point A and B, I want to create this points clicking on map.

[Here is my test with the full code, if needed.](http://www.inventoresdegaragem.com/dbteste/index.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [MapsEventListenter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener) listening for the click on the map.

The [Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) [click event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent) has a latLng property.  Capture the first one for your start location, the second for your end address (you will probably want to add some logic to either let your user drag them or delete them if they get them wrong).